# Method takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

My method actually gets 2 arguments other than self:

```
class MyService(object):
    def my_method(self, instance, **kwargs):
```

In the test code:

```
my_service.my_method(old_instance, new_data)
```

and Python says that:

```
takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Actually method has self among arguments so I was expecting to have no problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `new_data` ? is it a dictionary?

Comment: `new_data` is a regular argument while `my_method` is looking for **keyword** arguments. Try `my_service.my_method(old_instance, new_data = new_data)`

Comment: use ```*args``` to store the ```new_data```.
class MyService(object):
    def my_method(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments mentioned, my mistake was to pass a dictionary of values:

```
my_service.my_method(old_instance, {name: "New Value"})
```

But the proper way is:

```
my_service.my_method(old_instance, name = "New Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding *args to your method, so it looks like this:

```
class MyService(object):
    def my_method(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):
```